# JavaScript - getting "res.json is not a function" error when testing with Mocha

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

I have the following function that i'm testing:

```
module.exports = {

    post: function myFunc(req, res) {
        some logic...
        ...
        ...
        res.json(ObjectToReturn);

}
}
```

And i'm trying to test in with Mocha like so:

```
  it("some test", function() {

      const response = myModule.post(
                           { reqPayLoad }, 
                           {}
                              );
      console.log(response)
  });
```

But i'm keep getting the error:

> res.json is not a function

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object literal being passed to `post` is empty: `{}`,

In order to test this, you'd need to mock it out.

```
myModule.post(
    { reqPayLoad }, 
    { json: () => {} }
);
```

There's another problem here though.  Your `post` method does not actually return anything, so `response` will be undefined.

Instead, res.json() is being called to send the data back to the client, so you're going to need to inspect what that's being called with.

You might modify the mocked `json` method to log the result:

```
myModule.post(
    { reqPayLoad }, 
    { json: data => console.log(data) }
);
```

In order to actually test the returned value of `post` though, you're probably going to need something like Sinon [spies](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.3.2/spies/) to let you inspect what res.json() is being called with programmatically.

```
let jsonSpy = sinon.spy();
myModule.post(
    { reqPayLoad }, 
    { json: jsonSpy }
);

assert(jsonSpy.calledWith(ObjectThatWasReturned));
```

---

### Update

If the `post` method is asynchronous, you'll also need some way to wait for it to complete.  In my opinion, the simplest way to do that is by using [async/await](https://mochajs.org/#using-async-await)

```
    // async makes the function return a promise
    post: async function myFunc(req, res) {
        some logic...
        ...
        ...
        res.json(ObjectToReturn);

}
```

Then, we await the promise inside the test:

```
  // Note: we set this function as async as well
  it("some test", async function() {

    let jsonSpy = sinon.spy();
    // wait for the promise to resolve
    await myModule.post(
        { reqPayLoad }, 
        { json: jsonSpy }
    );

    assert(jsonSpy.calledWith(ObjectThatWasReturned));
  });
```

### Update Using Callbacks

Check out the Mocha docs on testing async code.  Here's an example:

```
it("some test", function(done) {

    // wait for the promise to resolve
    await myModule.post(
        { reqPayLoad }, 
        { 
            json: returnObject => {
                assert(returnObject).toEqual('some_object')
                done()
            } 
    }
    );
  });
```

Comment: What is `data` in `let jsonSpy = sinon.spy(data);` ?

Comment: That should have been removed, I've updated the answer

Comment: It doesn't work when i use `sinon.assert.calledOnce(jsonSpy)` :/
It says it wasn't called at all (0 times).

Comment: Is there any asynchronous code being run inside of ```post```?

Comment: Yes there is some.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately i can't change the function's code :(

Comment: I've updated with a link to the async docs and a basic example for using the callback